# Is there a choose accented characters à la Android, without resorting to Alt + xxxx codes?

Tags: windows, keyboard, diacritics

I'm looking for a solution to type accented characters as simply as on Android:

[image]

Currently, I have to use either the ALT sequence (eg. ALT + 0201 to get É) or Windows' Charmap utility, but Android's solution is much easier to use.

I Googled for it, but found no solution. Is there really no similar solution on Windows?

--

Edit: To clarify, I'm looking for a solution that performs the same trick as the one shown on Android, ie. display a list of characters after the user has long-pressed the letter, and ideally, the solution should work with any version of Windows, regardless of release number and language.

Comment: Clarify your question by indicating the language and layout of your keyboard. On an English US-international keyboard you can type **é** using **' + e**, and **É** using **' + SHIFT + E**, which is much shorter than using ALT.

Comment: @mjavu - well, a) it's AZERTY & b) says Français, so French would be a fair first guess ;)

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: You could try Wincompose (https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose). It works in a different way than the Android keyboard, but I find it quite useful myself. For instance to type é, I have to type `[Ctrl]` `e` `'`

Comment: Thanks for the tip on WinCompose. More googling revealed www.holdkey.eu which is pretty close to how Android solved the problem